# Submit a form through Jquery to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a link and when the user clicks the link, I need to submit a form which will call a controller in my servlet.

Here is the jQuery code:

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" id="vehreport">Vehicle Availability Report</a></li>

<form method="post" id="vehiclereportform"
    action="/AutoNew/VehicleAvailiability">
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#vehreport").click(function(e) {
      alert('Hi')
        $("#vehiclereportform").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The form gets submitted but the controller is not called. There is no action once it displays "Hi".

Comment: looks like you're missing a semi-colon (`;`) after the `alert` ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#vehreport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Hi');
    $("#vehiclereportform").submit();
});
```

Comment: looks like the correct answer, but please point out what you have changed to resolve the issue...

Comment: Its not working yet..WHen I try $('#vehiclereportform') in my console it does not return the form object...Not sure why the form is not recognized in the page